# Как можно получить баннер с репутацией к себе на сайт?

Tags: поддержка, визитка

Подскажите, как можно к себе на сайт вставить баннер со своей репутацией типа этого, ну или в какой-то другой подобной форме?

Через сложные манипуляции с API не подходит, нужно просто картинкой, если такая возможность есть.

[image: Баннер с репутацией участника]

Answer (score 19):

На странице [настроек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) выбрать раздел "Визитка". Скопировать оттуда код. Будет типа такого:

[image: Профиль участника Suvitruf на сайте «Stack Overflow на русском», Вопросы и ответы для программистов]

Comment: Это прям целый квест с выбором темы визитки))

Comment: О ужас, и здесь это проклятое "`типО`"! Ведь [пишется](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/типа) "`типА`"! Легко же дойти логическими рассуждениями (а айтишники же их любят!), что эта частица происходит от родительного падежа слова "`тип`":
– `Вчера купил классный пирог!`
– `Какой?` = `Какого типа?`
– `Ну яблочный` = `Яблочного типа` = `Типа яблочного`

Comment: @AivanF. я с деревни, тут плохо с грамотностью. Спасибо за негодование )

Comment: @Suvitruf **из** деревни ;)